# Защита программы от pyautogui

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

Играюсь с библиотекой для питона - pyautogui. Совершаю простейшие команды: передвигаю курсор, кликаю по кнопкам, ввожу текст в текстовые поля. В большинстве случаев все работает корректно, но в некоторых программах происходит сбой - курсор мыши передвигается в нужные координаты, но клика по кнопке не происходит ( программы не выполняет те действия, которые должна по клику на соответствующую кнопку), текст также не вводиться. Мне кажется в таких программах предусмотрена некая защита от автоматических действий. Мне интересно как она работает? Как ее можно обойти? Как ее реализовать в своей программе?
Единственное что пришло в голову, это "отсеивание" по задержке действия, но ее различные варианты не дали результата. 
Еще одна деталь которую заметил, текст ( тот что должен вводиться в текстовое поле) после завершения скрипта появляется в PowerShell, именно через него я запускаю скрипт.

Comment: Программа не получила клик - значит не получила фокус - поэтом и текст остался в поверщели

Comment: Нет, фокус переходит на поле ввода, это заметно по появляющемуся указателю ввода. Программно я могу переключаться между различными текстовыми полями, но вести в текстовое поле ничего не выходит. При клике в окне программы, оно становиться активным, но клик по кнопкам, не фиксируется( программа не воспринимает его), сочетание горячих клавиш(например разворот программы на полный экран или вставка текста) также не работают..

Comment: приведите пример программы

Comment: import pyautogui as ag
import time

time.sleep(2)

ag.moveTo(520, 740, duration=0.3)
ag.click(duration=0.3)
time.sleep(0.3)

param = ag.locateOnScreen('test.png')
if param:
    x, y, w, h = param
    ag.moveTo(x + 50, y - 30, duration=0.3)
    ag.click(duration=0.3)
    time.sleep(1)

    ag.moveTo(x + 50, y - 80, duration=0.3)
    ag.click(duration=0.3)
    time.sleep(1)

    pg.typewrite('hello', 0.5)
    time.sleep(1)

    ag.moveTo(x + 40, y + 15)
    ag.click(duration=0.3)

Comment: Которые не кликаются